# Looking for a Python dict comprehension from a loop I wrote

Tags: python, list, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I'm new to Python and trying to write a dictionary comprehension from this for loop:

```
    results = []
    for line in self.data:
        if value in line:
            item = dict(zip(self.keys, line))
            results.append(item)
        continue
    return results
```

self.keys is a list self.data is a list of lists of values that belong to those keys.  Basically, I have a list of values from the top of a tab-delimited text file (the keys) and then a bunch of rows of for the values of the actual items represented in the file:

```
[scene, take, camera]
[12, 1, A]
[12, 1, B]
[12, 2, A]
[12, 2, B]
```

etc...

I want,

```
{scene:12, take:1, camera:A}
```

The code I have works, but I'm trying to learn so I'm wondering if someone can teach me how to write that as a comprehension.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks,

Dan

Comment: The `continue` is redundant

Comment: Aside: have you heard of [`csv.DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader)?

Comment: Hello Matt.  I didn't try anything that gave me anything other than a syntax error so I didn't keep any of it to paste here, sorry.

Comment: Hello DSM.  No, I have not heard of that, but I'm not allowed to actually import anything.  I'm supposed to write this using only built-ins.

Comment: Padriac Cunningham, sorry.  I should have included the first line of the def.     def dicts(self, value):

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what I can understand from the question, this should work

```
result=[dict(zip(self.keys, line)) for line in self.data if value in line]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
return [dict(zip(self.keys, line)) for line in self.data if value in line]
```

This would actually be a list comprehension, since we're building a list.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you can simplify your code to:

```
results = []
for line in self.data:
    if value in line:
        item = dict(zip(self.keys, line))
        results.append(item)
return results
```

This shows your looping is `for line in self.data`, your value is `dict(zip(self.keys, line))` and your condition is `value in line`, so you put the value, then loop, then conditional - `[value loop conditional]. Your list comprehension becomes:

```
result = [dict(zip(self.keys, line)) for line in self.data if value in line]
return result
```

You can eliminate `result`, to give you:

```
return [dict(zip(self.keys, line)) for line in self.data if value in line]
```

However, as DSM points out, you can simply do:

```
import csv
with open("...") as f:
    return list(csv.DictReader(f, fieldnames=next(f).strip().split(), dialect="excel_tab"))
```